# How can I download files from my Android app?

Tags: android

I have an app, which needs to download some files from server and use them.

1. How can I download them? Techniques and samples are welcome.
2. Where can I store these files, so that my app might use them in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `AsyncTask` to do this type of functionality. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog) link for reference.